# ASP MVC - Bundles creating directory path instead of file path

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Styles/Default").Include("~/Content/Styles/Default/Site.css"));
```

And it creates this:

```
<link href="/Content/Styles/Default?v=HG5hShy6_NaqI7SUDWQuc6zijexRxZooKF4ayIgK5tY1" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now, i enabled directory browsing on my webserver, and when I click that style path, it moves me to a directory, and not to a file! Why?

**Update:** I still did not manage to solve that question, all i get when i go on the link `http://myserver/Content/Styles/Default?v=HG5hShy6_NaqI7SUDWQuc6zijexRxZooKF4ayIgK5tY1` is a list of files (like on a ftp)

Comment: Try this instead **bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Styles/Default/Site.css")**

Comment: But what if I wanted to add multiple files?

Comment: @Kundan Singh Chouhan: I just tried your solution, and all i got from that is: `<link href="/Content/Styles/Default" rel="stylesheet">`. What is going on...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First take a look at this [article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

> Bundling is a new feature in ASP.NET 4.5 that makes it easy to combine
>   or bundle multiple files into a single file. You can create CSS,
>   JavaScript and other bundles. Fewer files means fewer HTTP requests
>   and that can improve first page load  performance.
>
> The request

`http://localhost/MvcBM_time/bundles/AllMyScripts?v=r0sLDicvP58AIXN_mc3QdyVvVj5euZNzdsa2N1PKvb81`

> is for the bundle AllMyScripts and contains a query string pair
>   v=r0sLDicvP58AIXN_mc3QdyVvVj5euZNzdsa2N1PKvb81.
>
> The query string v has
>   a value token that is a unique identifier used for caching. As long as
>   the bundle doesn't change, the ASP.NET application will request the
>   AllMyScripts  bundle using this token. If any file in the bundle
>   changes, the ASP.NET optimization framework will generate a new token,
>   guaranteeing that browser requests for the bundle will get the latest
>   bundle

This is how to add directory with files

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/jQueryUI/themes/baseAll")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/Content/themes/base", "*.css"));
```

This is how to add multiple files:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
          "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css"));
```

Comment: Well, and I have added a file, and it is pointing to a directory! :/

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but Google pointed me here when I was searching for a solution so I thought I would add what worked for me.

I had the same problem as you and ran across this other question that I believe is the same:

[MVC4 - Bundling does not work when optimizations are set to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240097/mvc4-bundling-does-not-work-when-optimizations-are-set-to-true)

> I imagine the problem is you putting the bundle at a virtual URL that actually exists, but is a directory.

Changing the bundle path fixed the problem I was having.