# js and css filename being corrupted on publish with VS2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, filenames

I am publishing my Web App using the VS2013 publish mechanism.  For some reason it has just started corrupting the js and css filenames. e.g. 
From

`<link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

To

`<link href="/Content/css?v=puREEettBuwGkRK7y27hOQwXg4qvcAYRnG8wxc0gvnU1" rel="stylesheet"/>`

This is only happening on publish to the live site. It works fine on publish to the localhost site. It looks like possibly some kind of versioning.
The defined bundles in BundleConfig are not being expanded, instead parsed with the above result.
 Any ideas? I have not seen it before and its not showing up on Google searches. Thanks for any suggestions.

ANSWER:
For anyone else getting this problem - Once I realised it was the Bundles I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240097/mvc4-bundling-does-not-work-when-optimizations-are-set-to-true) which gave a lots of thoughts. However my specific issue was that I had installed Select2 via NuGet which had added a css directory in Content. As I was creating a Bundle pointing at Content\css these clashed. I removed the css directory and republished. Still didn't work. But when I removed that directory on the server manually it all started working again.