# Bundling in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I want this to be bundle in one css file and I am not sure why it is not working with following code ... can any one tell me where I am missing code to make this bundle one css file..

.cs

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").IncludeDirectory("~/Content/themes/base", "*.css")); 
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

.cshtml

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
```

Rendered markup

```
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.base.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.menu.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.spinner.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.tooltip.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/annotations.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jquery.jstree.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/jstree.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/sidePanels.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/snapshot.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/superfish.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/toolbar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/themes/base/viewer.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Are you running in debug mode? Try release mode.

Comment: I think if you force this BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; it should do in debug mode too ... am I wrong?

Comment: According to the MS docs you are right. Does release version build bundle correctly? Or is something else amiss?

Comment: same error in release mode

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240097/mvc4-bundling-does-not-work-when-optimizations-are-set-to-true)