# Font Awesome not loading with Bundle Optimizations MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, font-awesome

As the title states, my font awesome (v4.5.0) will not load if I set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`. When it is set to `false` the file loads fine.

I have checked out a bunch of google and stackoverflow posts and all of them say I need to add `CssRewriteUrlTransform()` to my bundle config. I did that, so now my font awesome bundle looks like this:

```
bundles.Add((new StyleBundle("~/Content/fontawesome").Include("~/Content/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform())));
```

I have ensured the file exists and is in the correct location, but as I mentioned earlier it loads up fine when optimizations are disabled.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Seems likely your problem relates to using a real folder that actually exists as your bundle path.  Change your bundle name from `~/Content/fontawesome` to something like, say, `~/bundles/fontawesome` and see if it helps.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240097/mvc4-bundling-does-not-work-when-optimizations-are-set-to-true

Comment: Yup that seemed to be the case. Thanks!