# C# MVC - Styles not rendering when optimizations are set to true

Tags: c#, optimization, asp.net-mvc-5, styles, asp.net-bundling

I have  the following code in Config.cs:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"
                    ));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"
                  ));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css",
                  "~/Content/css/site.css", 
                  "~/Content/css/ab-style.css"));
```

The styles are not rendering correctly and [page](http://www.ananyabarta.com) is looking odd. But everything works fine when I set **BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false** in config.cs. Does anybody have a clue as to why this is happening.

NOTE: There is no Debug= "true" in Web.config and there is no conflict of virtual path as there is no "~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/bootstrap" ... folders in my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVC4 - Bundling does not work when optimizations are set to true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240097/mvc4-bundling-does-not-work-when-optimizations-are-set-to-true)

Comment: Probably this question - this has bit me before, try `new StyleBundle("~Content/css/all.css").Include(...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your bundle in virtual folder.

```
  bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css/AllMyCss.css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/font-awesome.min.css",
              "~/Content/css/site.css", 
              "~/Content/css/ab-style.css"));
```

and use the following code to render a bundle

```
@Styles.Render("~/content/css/AllMyCss.css")
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the issue. Perhaps there was a path conflict in the stylebundle.

Comment: I try this problem for two weeks. You are number one.