# Bundle not working in production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle

Below is mu code snippet for bundling :

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/scent-css").Include(
               "~/css/bootstrap.css",
               "~/css/custom.css"));
```

in my layout i am addind css file using :
**@Styles.Render("~/bundles/scent-css")**

Everything works fine on my machine , but when i moved all stuff to the local web server (IIS) the css files are not getting loaded. If I view the source of page in production environment I can see line:

```
<link href="/bundles/scent-css?v=v4ohyWx_1204EYiKV1yo4Pyg03bErnO8heg7POAEXP01" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

I have googled this and tried almost everything people suggested none of the solution worked so far.

I have tried : 
-adding  **bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();** in BundleConfig
-Edit the webconfig added :

```
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
<remove name="BundleModule" />
  <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here, why the css files are not loading.

Thanks

Comment: managed to fix it: [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240907/1680398)

Comment: How did you fix it? I have the same issue.

Comment: solution :https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240907/1680398